# myfaces 2.1 h:commandButton renders "Submit Query"

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

Strange issue, I have read through various posts, but have yet to find a working answer.

When I have a h:commandButton, where I want an icon to display instead of text, I have tried.

```
<h:commandButton value=" " image="UpArrow.png" style="position: absolute; left: 36px; top: 17px; width: 18px; height: 18px; cursor: pointer;" title="Pan up" actionListener="#{SarWindsImagesBean.panUp('testImage.jpg')}">
    <f:ajax  render="imagePan2"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton image="UpArrow.png" style="position: absolute; left: 36px; top: 17px; width: 18px; height: 18px; cursor: pointer;" title="Pan up" actionListener="#{SarWindsImagesBean.panUp('testImage.jpg')}">
    <f:ajax  render="imagePan2"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

In the first, the size is correct, but instead of the image, I get "Submit Query".
In the second, I get the same problem.

Why is it rendering "Submit Query"? and If I add value=" ", it will not display the icon, just an empty box.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the browser-default value of the HTML `<input type="submit">` element when the `value` attribute is omitted. This is not generated by JSF. Try it out yourself with such a HTML element in a plain HTML page.

As to why adding the `value` attribute when the `image` attribute is present results in an empty box, that's likely MyFaces specific. I can't reproduce it in Mojarra.

As to (ab)using the `image` attribute in order to present a background image, this after all not entirely right. You should be using CSS `background-image` property instead,

```
<h:commandButton value=" " style="background-image: url(UpArrow.png)" />
```

or just a `<h:commandLink><h:graphicImage>` if you don't want to have the appearance of a button at all:

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <h:graphicImage value="UpArrow.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thank you, with your help I was able to get all the button controls to work correctly for both javascript enabled and non-javascript enabled browsers.